# Web Essentials LESS Compiler gives no Error Messages

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, less, web-essentials

With Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, Web Essentials 2.7.

Suppose there is an error in LESS. When saving the file, a message is shown in the preview pane. It reads...

```
/*

Compile Error. 
See error list for details

*/
```

It does not matter, what kind of error is in the LESS. Any error is handled as above.

What can be done, so a detailed error message is given?

Comment: I get this as well. I emailed the creator, can't figure out what the error is since I don't get an error message.

Comment: Did you get an answer? Do you know whether this is a problem that anybody sees? Or does it only occur in special environments?

Comment: I looked through the entire file to eventually find a merge error that introduced a new line `@media print` that had no opening (or closing) brace. Disappointing that this isn't reported, or that there's no way to jump to the next error/warning. (ReSharper says "Analysing file..." and dies/ignores me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `@import` statments? If so, try switching to `@import-once`. That was my issue. The structure of my LESS directory calls for several "partials", many of which interact with the same base mixins or variable LESS file. To compile these files I had to add `@import "mixins.less"` to each of my partial files.

I then had a master LESS file which importing these partials, so if I were including 8 files, there would be those 8 `@import` statements as well as the `@import` statements in the partials. I think the LESS compiler couldn't handle the load, ran up to about 1.5 GB of memory and then broke. That was the message I was getting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It is no problem with @import. Even the following single line produces the error "body { color: (at)COLOR }" because of the unknown variable.

Comment: Oh. First thing, for the next time you should include a code sample so we could help you better. I was completely off on what you were talking about. What error do you get inside the `Error List` pane in Visual Studio? It sounds like you just aren't using the `@import-once` statement to include the file that contains the variable. Even if you are creating partials that only purpose is to be part of a master `@import` LESS file, you still need to import the neccesary files that contain the definitions for variables, mixins, etc.

Comment: The problem did not depend on the actual source code. There weren't any error messages at all. It had nothing to do with import or import-once. Even a single-line statement as above was rejected without a detailed message. I uninstalled Web Essentials, then re-installed them, and anything was fine again. Thank you.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when @mgs has said this is irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. What helped me was setting the issue type shown in the error list to "Build + IntelliSense" (see screenshot). After that the error was shown to me and i was able to fix it pretty easily. In "Build Only" the mode no errors that occurred in .less files were shown to me.
[image: Error List]