# LESS: Unrecognised input

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I'm trying to learn less with the help of Web Essentials 2012.

Right from the start, this LESS code:

```
@main-color: red;

.mega-warning {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: @main-color;
}
```

is giving a compile error "LESS: Unrecognised input" and the compilation stops. When i declare the variable `@main-color` inside the `.mega-warning` class scope everything works:

```
.mega-warning {
    @main-color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: @main-color;
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: had a similar problem doing @main-color = red insead of using : doesn't look like your code has this problem tho.

Comment: I had a similar problem with `@media (max-width: 20rem) // some comment here\n{`.  Putting the opening bracket before the comment fixed the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm struggling with the very same issue. Looks like Web Essentials 2012 v2.9 for some reason is not very happy about *.less files starting with variable declaration. Here is my workaround:

```
html{}

@main-color: red;

.mega-warning {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: @main-color;
}
```

Strangely enough things work absolutely fine when using standalone lessc 1.4.2 compiler (which is included in WE2012 2.9 as per [changelog](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog)). I've sent an email to the author of Web Essentials extensions and posted him a link to this question, so hopefully he'll address it pretty soon.

Comment: The issue is still there with VS 2012 Update 4 and latest WE (for the moment). This is quite bad :(.

Comment: @2ooom This is still happening.. not just with variable declaration, but anything starting with `@`

Answer (score 9):

Save less files with encoding **"UTF-8 without BOM"**. This approach was proposed in the post
[VS 2012 Web Essentials Less Compile Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909911/1588233)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Where you have added reference to less file:

```
rel="stylesheet/less"
```

With this your reference will look like

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Download less.js and add the `<script>` tag referencing it in the `<head>`.  The css `<link>` should come before the `<script>`.

Comment: I'm not adding a reference to the less file, the Web Essentials plugin generates a css file on the server side and that's where the issue comes from. I'd like to avoid client side preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VS / Web Essentials 2013. My fix was to recreate the `.less` file using a template. I had originally just changed the extension from `.css` to `.less`, but apparently that doesn't work. So use the Visual Studio template for a `.less` file instead.

I'm not positive where that `.less` template came from though, it might have come with Web Essentials, or it may have come in the [SideWaffle](http://sidewaffle.com/) template pack.